# no suitable constructor found for Exception

Tags: java, excepciones

en una aplicación `Java` con arquitectura `MVC` tengo una clase que se encarga de verificar los datos ingresados por el usuario.

```
    if (esCampoVacio(nombre)) {
        errorNombre = "No a ingresado ningun nombre";
        hayError = true;
    }else if (!esSoloLetras(nombre)) {
        errorNombre = "Nombre invalido";
        hayError = true;
    }

    if (esCampoVacio(apellido)) {
        errorApellido = "No a ingresado ningun apellido";
        hayError = true;
    }else if (!esSoloLetras(apellido)) {
        errorApellido = "Apellido invalido";
        hayError = true;
    }

    if (esCampoVacio(dni)) {
        errorDni = "No a ingresado ningun dni";
        hayError = true;
    }else if (!esNumero(dni)) {
        errorDni = "Dni invalido";
        hayError = true;
    }

    if (esCampoVacio(FondoInicial)) {
        errorFondoInicial = "No a ingresado ningun Fondo inicial";
        hayError = true;
    }else if (!esNumero(dni)) {
        errorFondoInicial = "Fondo inicial invalido";
        hayError = true;
    }


    if (hayError) {

    }
```

mi idea es que si ocurre uno o varios errores, enviar una excepción con un objeto que contenga todos los errores en forma de atributos, para poder tratarlos por separado en el `textfield` que ocurrió, mi duda es, como hago para poder lanzar ese objeto a través de la excepción.

yo probé creando mi propia excepción:

```
public class DatoErroneoException extends Exception{

public DatoErroneoException(NuevoClienteError error) {
    super(error);
 }
}
```

el error que me da es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nicolas, como estas lanzando la excepcion? El error indica que le estan enviando un string al constructor lo que no es valido

Comment: aun no hice la parte donde se lanza la exepcion, ese error me lo da por que le quiero pasar un objeto y no un string, mi duda es como le puedo pasar un objeto sin que me de error

Comment: Lo que le tienes que pasar a la excepción ese el objeto, no el string con el error. Si lo que quieres es enviar en la excepción todos los errores sería mejor que formaras un array de NuevoClienteError o que ese objeto tuviera un array de strings para almacenar los errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si haces que tu clase NuevoClienteError herede de Throwable, puedes mandar el objeto en la llamada  al constructor de Exception.

Tu clase del objeto error

```
public class NuevoClienteError extends Throwable{
private String error;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public NuevoClienteError(String msj) {
    super();
    error = msj;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return error;
}
}
```

Esta podría ser una exception propia

```
public class DatoErroneoException extends Exception{

public DatoErroneoException(NuevoClienteError oe) {
    super(oe);
}

}
```

Y lo lanzas así:

```
ObjetoError oe = new ObjetoError("Ha ocurrido un error");

    try {
        throw new MIE(oe);
    } catch (MIE e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y ya tanto en NuevoClienteError como como en DatoErroneoException desarrollas el código que necesites en tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que... la excepción que te lanza es por que no tienes un constructor que admita el parámetro que estás enviando... 
Yo también me lio un poco con las excepciones pero seguro que el aviso 
"Argument Mismatch" te está indicando que el constructor no admite ese tipo de parámetros.. 
podrías probar...

creando un constructor en el cual "se espere recibir" el tipo de dato que envías.